# Perl regex matching numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on a Perl assignment. One of the requirements is to match all integer and float numbers except those in comments or strings (double or single quoted).

Here is my assumption:

- Optional sign, integer, and fraction.
- If the integer part is omitted, the fraction is mandatory.
- If the fraction part is omitted, the decimal dot must be omitted.

And here is the regex I found.

```
([-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))
```

Here is my block of code, I had trouble to exclude numbers in comments and strings so I remove all comments and strings first. I also split lines into words, I believe this should be easier. But I also believe this should not be necessary.

```
while (<$IN_FILE>) {
    s/^(#[^!]+$)//;            # remove whole line comments
    s{(^[^#]+?)(#[^/]+$)}{$1}; # remove inline comments
    s/('.*?'|".*?")//g;        # remove all single line strings
    push @words, split;        # split line into words
  }

  foreach my $item (<@words>) {
    push @numbers, $1 if $item =~ /([-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))/;
  }
```

It worked ok but failed to match array index like the `0` in `ARGV[0]`.

So I need some help to improve my code, it would be nice if I don't have to remove comments, strings first, don't need to split lines into words, and of course match all the numbers not in comments and strings.

Simple input

```
# Comment 1
my $time = <STDIN>;
chomp $time;
   #now write input to STDOUT
print $time . "\n";
my $pi = 3.1415926;
my $test = -3.22;
my $t = +0.01;
my $range = (8..11);
if $ARGV[0];
sub sample2 {
   print "true or false";
   return 3 + 4 eq "7"; # true or false
}
```

Here is the output from my code it missed `0` in `ARGV[0]` and `11` in `(8..11)`. I won't be surprised if it misses more.

```
[Numbers]
3.1415926
-3.22
+0.01
8
2
3
4
```

Comment: Please add sample input data to your question.

Comment: If you're trying to parse Perl, use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI), not regex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is an assignment I am working on. Can't use any external modules.

Comment: Can you use **standard** Perl modules? There's a module called [Scalar::Utils](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) that has a function `looks_like_number`. Use that, and it'll pick up any type of number.

Comment: @David W. thanks for the info, the requirements is "identify all number using regular expression except those in comments and strings" so I don't think I can.

Comment: Too bad. The _identify a number_ regular expression is one of those tasks that's much trickier than it initially sounds. Others include verify a URL is in the correct format and verify an email address format. There's just way too many variables to be able to catch it in a single regular expression.

Comment: Actually I think this problem should have been split into two parts: 1:extracting "things" that are not inside comments or strings, and 2:check whether those "things" are numbers. Despite of that numbers can also have an exponent like `1.84467440737096e+19`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
foreach my $item (<@words>) {
```

You want to iterate over @words, so no `<>` are needed. They turn into `glob` which changes the list you want to iterate over. Just insert

```
warn "\t$item\n"
```

into the last loop to see what's being processed.

Even after fixing this, `(8..11)` will be tokenized into one "word". You match without any `/g`, so you cannot get more than one number from an item.

Answer (score 1):

As choroba already pointed out, your use of `<@words>` is an obvious bug.

However, you should simplify things by not breaking your lines into words in the first place and instead use `/g` to match

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/^(#[^!]+$)//;            # remove whole line comments
    s{(^[^#]+?)(#[^/]+$)}{$1}; # remove inline comments
    s/('.*?'|".*?")//g;        # remove all single line strings

    while (/([-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))/g) {
        push @numbers, $1;
    }
}

print "@numbers";

__DATA__
# Comment 1
my $time = <STDIN>;
chomp $time;
   #now write input to STDOUT
print $time . "\n";
my $pi = 3.1415926;
my $test = -3.22;
my $t = +0.01;
my $range = (8..11);
if $ARGV[0];
sub sample2 {
   print "true or false";
   return 3 + 4 eq "7"; # true or false
}
```

This will end up pulling too many results.  One solution is to add a word boundary before the numbers in the regex:

```
while (/([-+]?\b([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))\b/g) {
```

Outputs:

```
3.1415926 -3.22 +0.01 8 11 0 3 4
```

The best way to accomplish this is by using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) though.  That is definitely outside of the scope of what your professor is trying to teach you, but to demonstrate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Find all the barewords within the doc
my $nums = $doc->find( 'PPI::Token::Number' );
for (@$nums) {
    print $_->content, "\n";
}

__DATA__
# Comment 1
my $time = <STDIN>;
chomp $time;
   #now write input to STDOUT
print $time . "\n";
my $pi = 3.1415926;
my $test = -3.22;
my $t = +0.01;
my $range = (8..11);
if $ARGV[0];
sub sample2 {
   print "true or false";
   return 3 + 4 eq "7"; # true or false
}
```

Outputs:

```
3.1415926
-3.22
0.01
8
11
0
3
4
```